# Rendering a List in a Panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a Panel where I render a search-form. This works. 
My problem is rendering a List under that search-form (so in the same Panel).

This is what I've done so far:

```
Ext.define("TCM.view.UserSearch", 
{
    extend: "Ext.form.Panel",

    requires: 
    [
        "Ext.form.FieldSet",
        "Ext.List"
    ],

    xtype: "usersearch",

    config: 
    {
        scrollable:'vertical'
    },

    initialize: function () 
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        var clubsStore = Ext.create('TCM.store.Clubs');
        clubsStore.load();

        var usersStore = Ext.create('TCM.store.Users');

        var searchButton = 
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            text: 'Search',
            handler: this.onSearchButtonTap,
            scope: this
        };

        var topToolbar = 
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Search',
            items: [
                { xtype: 'spacer' },
                searchButton
            ]
        };

        var userClub = 
        {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            store: clubsStore,
            name: 'clubId',
            label: 'Club',
            displayField : 'name',
            valueField : 'id',
            required: true
        };

        var userList = 
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            store: usersStore,
            itemTpl: '{name}',
            title: 'Search results'
        };

        this.add([
            topToolbar,
            { 
                xtype: "fieldset",
                items: [userClub]
            }, 
            userList
        ]);
    },

    onSearchButtonTap: function () 
    {
        console.log("searchUserCommand");
        this.fireEvent("searchUserCommand", this);
    }
});
```

I can't see anything being rendered under the fieldset (the searchform). What could be wrong?

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you ? Then can you accept on of them or provide more details if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of time, when you don't see a component it's because you did not set a [layout](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-layout) to your container or a height.

[You can find more about layout here.](http://www.sencha.com/learn/intro-to-layouts-in-sencha-touch-2)

In your case, you want to have two components in your container. Therefore, I suggest a [Vbox layout](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.VBox).

[Here's an example](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#CBHvj)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used something like this in a project try this...Put this in the items property of your fieldset...

```
        {
            xtype: 'searchfield',
            clearIcon: true,
            placeHolder: 'Type Some text'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            hidden:true,  //Initially hidden populate as user types something
            height: '150px',
            pressedDelay: 1,
            loadingText: '',
            store: 'listStore',
            itemTpl: '{\'What you want to be displayed as per your model field\'}'
        }
```

In your controller write a handler for the keyup event of the searchfield to load the store with relevant data and toggle the hidden property of the list. Hopefully list should appear with the search results(Worked for me and looked quite good). Hope this helps...

Comment: I've got almost the same as you (except for pressedDelay, etc ...) but it doesn't work. What am I missing? :P